# Ubuntu is sending IPv6 packets with hop limit 0

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have had a working IPv6 Network (provided by a HE-Tunnelbroker) for a while. Everything still works perfectly fine on my Android phone.

But since the update to Ubuntu 15.04 my IPv6 connectivity doesn't work. (can't ping anything due to HL-exceeded), but traceroute works.

After some [packet captures](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8658299/hl0.pcapng) with wireshark I found out, that almost all IPv6 packets are sent with a hop limit of 0. The only exception are the traceroute tools, that specify HL manually.

```
$ping6 2a00:eb0:100::1
PING 2a00:eb0:100::1(2a00:eb0:100::1) 56 data bytes
From 2001:470:2042:15:: icmp_seq=1 Time exceeded: Hop limit
From 2001:470:2042:15:: icmp_seq=2 Time exceeded: Hop limit
From 2001:470:2042:15:: icmp_seq=3 Time exceeded: Hop limit
^C
--- 2a00:eb0:100::1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2016ms

$traceroute6 2a00:eb0:100::1
traceroute to 2a00:eb0:100::1 (2a00:eb0:100::1) from 2001:470:2070:15:d513:6f03:bdaf:3d7b, 30 hops max, 24 byte packets
 1  2001:470:2042:15::  0.45 ms  0.347 ms  0.333 ms
 2  2001:470:1f1a:4242::1  22.826 ms  22.893 ms  22.98 ms
 3  2001:470:0:2ba::1  22.352 ms  22.407 ms  22.787 ms
 4  2001:470:0:2b3::1  39.441 ms  28.973 ms  28.566 ms
 5  2001:7f8:30:0:2:1:3:9912  56.771 ms  41.27 ms  42.054 ms
 6  2a01:f8:666:70:81:94:57:76  41.417 ms  41.567 ms  40.937 ms
 7  2a01:f8:1:2:1:1:11:2  50.385 ms  51.238 ms  51.297 ms
 8  2a01:100:1027:77::2  50.967 ms  50.996 ms  50.967 ms
 9  2a00:eb0:100:815::20  50.919 ms  50.928 ms  50.247 ms
10  2a00:eb0:100:1000::1  53.559 ms  51.84 ms  52.188 ms

$ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 42:42:80:7a:62:94  
          inet Adresse:10.15.255.252  Bcast:10.15.255.255  Maske:255.255.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: 2001:470:2042:15:4242:80ff:fe7a:6294/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: 2001:470:2042:15:d513:6f03:bdaf:3d7b/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Global
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::4242:80ff:fe7a:6294/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:40876 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:30562 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:45527753 (45.5 MB)  TX-Bytes:3439757 (3.4 MB)
```

NOTE: IPv6 addresses are obfuscated for privacy reasons

Comment: Does `grep '^[^#]' /etc/sysctl.conf` or `head /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*/hop_limit` provide any useful hints?

Comment: Anything interesting happening in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: in /etc/sysctl.conf all lines are commented (starting with #) If I set the hop_limit file to 64 it works until the next reboot, when it is reset to 0 again

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a temporary solution, that works until you reboot the PC.

```
#echo 64 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/hop_limit
```